# Dojo Grid and Enhanced Grid showing same value differently

Tags: dojo

The actual value of a column is N/A, after encoding using OWASP ESAPI the value is converted to "N/A". If we use Grid the value is showing properly as "N/A" where as for Enhanced Grind the same value is showing as "N/A". Why it is behaving differently, what is the formatter that grid is using. How to show proper value in Enhanced Grid

Comment: can you create fiddle or add some code here where we can reproduce same error..

Comment: Sorry this wrong question.

Comment: ohk no problem.. just delete this...